# ffmpeg cut to frames and merge without quality loss

Tags: ffmpeg, video

I am trying to cut a mpg file to frames, and subsequently merging them again with ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mpg -vsync 0 -q:v 2 temp/%03d.bmp
ffmpeg -i  temp/%03d.bmp  -y  output.mpg
```

My goal is to obtain the same video again, but currently it decreases a lot in quality. How can I make sure the quality stays the same?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Technically you can't because the default encoder (mpeg1video) for `.mpg` is a lossy encoder. It's called [generation loss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generation_loss).

For mpeg1video you can make it have a higher quality by adding `-q:v 2`:

```
ffmpeg -i temp/%03d.bmp -q:v 2 output.mpg
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Are there non-lossy encoders for mpg?

Comment: @user3053216 ffmpeg will allow you to arbitrarily mux the lossless variant of H.264, but the question becomes, what formats does your application support? I doubt it will like that.